# iPod App crashes on launch

Tags: objective-c, crash, ipod

Is it normal that when i try to test my app it crashes on launch?

I explain.

I have my app that works fine in the simulator. I wanted to try to test it on my iPod Touch 4g.

I built and run from XCode, and that's what happened: the app launches fine (it shows me a black splash screen),but then suddenly it comes back to the springboard,with no reason.

If i open up the app manually,after it crashed,it works without any problems. It happens only one time,just when i build and run,and i don't know why.

How can i do to avoid this? On simulator it works with any crashes,but when i run it over my iPod,it crashes.

```
Program ended with exit code: 0 // on simulator
```

Comment: Please use actual meaningful tags - such as a language and platform - so that people will actually understand the context of your question. It also behooves you to do this since most users filter by tags and programming languages + platforms are common filter choices. I sincerely doubt anyone is on the edge of their seat following the `[at]` tag.

Comment: While it is normal to write code with bugs, it's not good to leave them there. Especially if they crash your app.

Comment: I would like to know the reason why it crashes,it happens only on launch. In the code i released everything,i can't understand why it keeps crashing on launch everytime i build and run it from xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is likely to be failing to run on the device as xcode is trying to attach the debugger to it but doesn't have permission to do so.

Check your entitlements.plist within your project; you probably have one that has `get-task-allow` set to `NO`. This needs to be 'YES' to allow the debugger to attach. (It does need to be 'NO' for adhoc builds though - one solution is to exclude the entitlements.plist file from the debug build.)

Comment: Ops,my bad. By the way,i added the "Entitlements.plist" to my project and set "Can be debugged" on YES. But the crashes still happen. I repeat though, it crashes only when i build and run directly from Xcode.

Comment: Check the console for clues (window->organizer->console). Also check you're using your development provisioning profile to sign the app (in the xcode project settings), not an adhoc one. Failing only from 'build and run' does definitely sound like a problem in this area.

Comment: Console says this:  http://i51.tinypic.com/2d76j2w.jpg  Seems like the app is not going to open up or?

Comment: Uh,i tried to turn on Breakpoints,and seems that it's working. i would understand why,if i turn off breakpoints,it doesn't show up when i build and run. weird thing